# Memmap in MATLAB for huge arrays

Tags: python, matlab, memory

I want to create a [`memmap`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memmapfile.html) in MATLAB. 
In python I could do this by:

```
ut = np.memmap('my_array.mmap', dtype=np.float64, mode='w+', shape=(140000,3504))
```

Then I use it as a normal array, the OS ensured my memory never overflowed. How to do this in MATLAB?

From the docs it seems it wants me to create some array in MATLAB first then write it to a file and read using `memmap`!

Matlab docs are not clear enough:
Please provide an example of creating an random array of size (140000,15000) and multiply it some other similar matrix.

Comment: What I understand from the documentation is that you cannot create **one** array which is bigger than your RAM, e.g. one 200GB array, but you can create e.g. 200 1GB arrays, which you store in a temporary location on disk which is accessible in a slower way than RAM, but faster than a full write-to-file script.

Comment: There are examples on the Mathworks website...

Comment: @IKavanagh Matlab docs seem inefficient in explaining it in detail. Adriaan comment is very helpful for start. Still have doubts on to apply a elementary-wise operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create an empty file first, then use memmapfile:

```
size=[140000,3504];
filesize=0;
datatype='float64';
filename='my_array.dat';
fid=fopen(filename,'w+');
max_chunk_size=1000000;
%fills an empty file
while filesize<prod(size)
    to_write=min(prod(size)-filesize,max_chunk_size);
    filesize=filesize+fwrite(f, zeros(to_write,1), datatype);
end   
fclose(fid);
m = memmapfile(filename,'Format','double', 'Writable',true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! Can you please also tell how to perform some operation on the array.

Comment: What kind of operations?

Comment: Matlab says the memmap canbe used just like other normal arrays. So how to appl any operation say transpose on `m.Data` without blowing my RAM.

Comment: Transposing requires to reorganize the full data, that's something you typically want to avoid at all costs when dealing with such data sizes. Try to apply MapReduce or similar to create multiple steps dealing with smaller data.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the function [`memmapfile`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memmapfile.html)

Example:

```
m = memmapfile('my_array.dat','Format','double', 'Writable',true)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of creating random array of size '5000x153600'.

Comment: that function won't create a file by itself, aifk you need to first create a file of sufficient size. For example with a combination of fopen and fprintf. You can do so in a loop if the array is too big to hold in memory.

Comment: I tried this :` >> m = memmapfile('my_array.dat','Format','double', 'Writable',true);
Error using memmapfile/hChangeFilename (line 351)
Cannot access file "my_array.dat": No such file or directory.

Error in memmapfile (line 568)
        obj = hChangeFilename(obj, filename);`. Can you please explain by example.

Comment: You have to create the file first.

Comment: @Daniel that will crash my RAM.